# Drawing an Inflection Point with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a point of inflection with this program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(6,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,6) node[left] {$y$};
\coordinate (1) at (.5,2.75);
\coordinate (2) at (1.5,4.5);
\coordinate (3) at (3,3);
\coordinate (4) at (4.5,1.5);
\coordinate (5) at (5.5,3.25);
\draw [name path=curve,red,thick,-] (1) to[out=80,in=180] (2) 
 to[out=0,in=135] (3) to[out=315,in=180] (4) to[out=0,in=260] (5);
\draw[fill] (3,3) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This outputs: You can see a small "kink" in the graph

[image]

How can I get the plot smoother at the point P? As in

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a minimal modification of your code using the `sin` and `cos` paht constructions, which are explained in section 2.12 of the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(6,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,6) node[left] {$y$};
\coordinate (1) at (.5,2.75);
\coordinate (2) at (1.5,4.5);
\coordinate (3) at (3,3);
\coordinate (4) at (4.5,1.5);
\coordinate (5) at (5.5,3.25);
\draw [red,thick,-] (1)sin (2) 
 cos (3) sin (4) cos (5);
\draw[fill] (3) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also plot a function....

Comment: yes I thought about a function but chose this way and then had the problem. I will read the manual where you indicated. It works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Just choose more accurate values for the `in` and `out` around the inflection point, like `.. in=120] (3) to[out=300 ..`, and add some `looseness` for more smoother curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(6,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,6) node[left] {$y$};
\coordinate (1) at (.5,2.75);
\coordinate (2) at (1.5,4.5);
\coordinate (3) at (3,3);
\coordinate (4) at (4.5,1.5);
\coordinate (5) at (5.5,3.25);
\draw [red,thick,looseness=.8] (1) to[out=80,in=180] (2) 
 to[out=0,in=120] (3) to[out=300,in=180] (4) to[out=0,in=260] (5);
\draw[fill] (3,3) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Since you drew this curve by approximation, I show you another way to draw this same curve by approximation.

Bezier curves can be used by indicating the control points for the start and finish point *(as indicated on page 140 of the manual)*. Here, only the starting points `(1)` and arrival points `(5)` are sufficient, the others are useless.

I drew the tangents used by the Bézier curve in cyan. 
To place the inflection point, always by approximation, I used the `decorations.markings` library.

[image: point d'inflexion]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
markings,
mark=at position .55 with \fill circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};}]
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(6,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,6) node[left] {$y$};
\coordinate (1) at (.5,2.75);
\coordinate (5) at (5.5,3.25);

\draw[postaction={decorate}] (1) ..controls +(75:7) and +(-110:6)..(5);
\draw[cyan,->] (1) -- +(75:7);
\draw[cyan,<-] (5) -- +(-110:6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All of you have been great for giving a good answer to the user's question. My most sincere appreciation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I always try to be as simple and clear as possible, professional deformation obliges me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using geometric transformations is my favourite (in this case, P(2,2) is the center of symmetry).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,4) node[left] {$y$};
\def\rightpath{
    (2,2) ..controls +(-70:.5) and +(-100:2)..  (3,2.5)
}
\draw[red,thick]\rightpath; 
\draw[red,thick,rotate around={180:(2,2)}]\rightpath;
\draw[dashed] (2,2)--(2,0) node[below]{$x_0$}
node[below=3mm,red]{$f''(x_0)=0$};
\fill (2,2) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]